# 'phantomjs' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, phantomjs

This script works fine on Google Cloud Service. But i get error on Amazon Web Service EC2: (operation system: linux 64bit)

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable may have wrong permissions.
```

Full Code:

```
 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py:49: UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1499, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "turkish.py", line 114, in <module>
    bot = TransBot()
  File "turkish.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable may have wrong permissions.
```

I try move '/usr/local/bin' and '/usr/local/share' phantomjs file. Same error. What do you suggest? Sorry my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the permissions so it is executable.

`$ chmod a+x phantomsjs`

Comment: Oh thank you. I did run 'chmod a+x phantomsjs' in terminal. Then i get error:
'phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127'
Then i install libfontconfig and problem solved.
'yum install fontconfig freetype freetype-devel fontconfig-devel libstdc++'

Answer (score 1):

Grant full permission to the phantomjs file :

```sh
sudo chmod a+rwx phantomjs
```